# awk: how to "nextfile" in ENDFILE?

Tags: awk

refer to "The GNU Awk User's Guide"

> The next statement (see section The next Statement) is not allowed inside either a BEGINFILE or an ENDFILE rule. The nextfile statement is allowed only inside a BEGINFILE rule, not inside an ENDFILE rule.

I have tested "nextfile" in BEGINFILE：
**Even if nextfile is written in BEGINFILE, the corresponding file in ENDFILE will be executed**

I wonder how can I skip the "file" that "nextfile" in BEGINFILE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is "can we use nextfile inside ENDFILE section" Then short answer is no, we can't use it.

***Here is an example:***

- ***Use of `nextfile` in `BEGINFILE` section:*** Let's say we have 2 Input_files named file1 and file2.
  Let us run `nextfile` inside `BEGINFILE` rule.

```
awk 'BEGINFILE{print FILENAME;nextfile} 1' file1 file2
file1
file2
```

We could see its printing Input_file names in it and NOT printing the contents of files, means its working fine.

- ***Use of `nextfile` inside `ENDFILE` block:*** Now lets run `nextfile` inside `ENDFILE` section and see what happens.

```
awk '1;ENDFILE{nextfile;print "bla bla"}' file1 file2
awk: cmd. line:1: error: `nextfile' used in ENDFILE action
```

It gives an error as you see above. Why this is happening, because `ENDFILE` OR `END` blocks always get executed after all the records of Input_file(s) are done with executing, so in case you want to jump to next Input_file then you could either use it in `BEGINFILE` OR `BEGIN` section OR use it in `main block` of your code in case you want to match specific condition and then jump to next Input_file.

---

---

***How to skip `ENDFILE` section for a specific Input_file:*** If you have an `ENDFILE` statement then on each Input_file's record reading, then to skip a specific Input_file we could use condition like this:

```
awk '1;ENDFILE{if(FILENAME!="file2"){print FILENAME}}' file1 file2
```

Output will be as follows.

```
bla bla bla file1 contents here.....
file1
bla bnla bla file2 contents here....
```

Basically its print contents of Input_file1 and Input_file2 but because a condition is mentioned in `ENDFILE` block its NOT printing file2 name in output, hence prevented a statements from execution in `ENDFILE` block here.

---

---

***Ideal use of `nextfile` in `BEGINFILE` block:*** If we use `nextfile` inside `BEGINFILE` block then it will for sure NOT going to print any of the records of that specific Input_file, why because `BEGINFILE` block's statements gets executed before reading records from Input_file when we mention `nextfile` it will NOT start reading records process and will simply jump to next Input_file.

***So when to use `nextfile` in `BEGINFILE` block?:*** IMHO one of the BEST use case will be when we want to process multiple Input_file(s) and want to deal with headers for each Input_file(eg--> print only header OR a message for specific file and DO NOT process records of that Input_file). OR 2nd case I could think of if any processing you need to do before executing the records of that Input_file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! Now I use conditions in **ENDFILE**, I just want to find a **more elegant way** to achieve a function similar to **nextfile**

Comment: @dancedpipi, you use `nextfile` itself but have some condition in it. Like one I showed with file name in case for specific file name you want to skip I showed it. You could go it with few other ways too but since it was not your basic question so I had just given an example only, cheers and happy learning

Comment: Thanks a lot, you save me a lot time.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the GNU awk manual, then it states this about `nextfile`:

> In gawk, execution of `nextfile` causes additional things to happen: any `ENDFILE` rules are executed if gawk is not currently in an `END` or `BEGINFILE` rule, `ARGIND` is incremented, and any `BEGINFILE` rules are executed.
>
> With gawk, `nextfile` is useful inside a `BEGINFILE` rule to skip over a file that would otherwise cause gawk to exit **with a fatal error**. In this case, `ENDFILE` rules **are not executed**.
>
> **<sub>source: [GNU awk manual: nextfile statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Nextfile-Statement)</sub>**

**So, what does this mean?**

- `ENDFILE` is executed if `nextfile` is in a normal pattern-action pair (`pattern { action }`)

  ```
  $ awk '{nextfile}1;ENDFILE{print "processing ENDFILE"}' /dev/random
  processing ENDFILE
  ```
- `ENDFILE` is executed if `nextfile` is in a BEGINFILE-block  (`BEGINFILE { action }`)

  ```
  $ awk 'BEGINFILE{print "processing BEGINFILE with error", ERRNO; nextfile}1
         ENDFILE{print "processing ENDFILE"}' /dev/random
  processing BEGINFILE with error 
  processing ENDFILE
  ```
- `ENDFILE` is **not** executed if `nextfile` is in a BEGINFILE-block **and an error** occurred (`BEGINFILE { action }`)

  ```
  $ touch foo; chmod -r foo
  $ awk 'BEGINFILE{print "processing BEGINFILE with error", ERRNO; nextfile}1
          ENDFILE{print "processing ENDFILE"}' foo
  processing BEGINFILE with error Permission denied
  ```

**How can we skip `ENDFILE` using `nextfile`?**

The answer is to fake an error. By assigning anything to the Gnu variable `ERRNO`, you will skip the `ENDFILE` block

```
$ awk 'BEGINFILE{ERRNO=1; print "processing BEGINFILE with error", ERRNO; nextfile}1 
       ENDFILE{print "processing ENDFILE"}' /dev/random
processing BEGINFILE with error 1
```

Comment: Setting `ERRNO` doesn't cause `ENDFILE` to be skipped in gawk 5.1.0. This may be a bug - according to the docs `ENDFILE` should always be skipped if `nextfile` is used in `BEGINFILE`, regardless of the value of `ERRNO`. I'll follow up with the gawk maintainers to find out if it's a bug or a documentation issue.

Comment: @EdMorton I need to check which version I used to test this, but I believe it was 4.2.1

Comment: Arnold replied he thinks it's a documentation issue and he'll update that, see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2020-11/msg00003.html. Did you try `nextfile` in `BEGINFILE` **without** setting `ERRNO` to see if it was actually setting that that made a difference?

Comment: @EdMorton I've covered all cases in the above. Calling `nextfile` in `BEGINFILE`without an error still calls `ENDFILE` (see second example above)

Comment: OK, seems to me like aside from the documentation issue that Arnold is going to fix, some time between 4.2.1 and 5.1.0 they just fixed a bug or otherwise changed the behavior where manually setting ERRNO=1 (as opposed to actually encountering an error) would cause ENDFILE to be skipped.